# Ajax dynamic select dropdown in rails 5

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

Trying to populate US county from database by selected state from same table. Trying to implement in Rails 5 using this approach [here is the link](https://kernelgarden.wordpress.com/2014/02/26/dynamic-select-boxes-in-rails-4/)

So far I was able to figured out and see call being made and proper data return in browser console, but dropdown never gets updated. I was trying to messing around with different routes but still no luck. Please, any help would be appreciated.

```
#routes
get 'account/main/_update_weather', :to => 'client/main#_update_weather', :as 
=> :client_location_java
get 'account/_location', :to => 'client/main#_location', :as => 
:client_location

#controller ../controllers/client/main_controller.rb       
def _location
@weathers = Weather.all
@profile = Profile.new
@county_name = Weather.where("state_code = ?", "AL")
end

def _update_weather
@county_name = Weather.where("state_code = ?", params[:state_code])
respond_to do |format|
format.js
end
end

#Ajax /assets/javascripts/location.js.coffee
 $ ->
 $(document).on 'change', '#state_select', (evt) ->
 $.ajax 'main/_update_weather',
  type: 'GET'
  dataType: 'html'
  data: {
    state_code: $("#state_select option:selected").val()
  }
  success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
    console.log("Dynamic county select OK!")
  error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
    console.log("AJAX Error: #{textStatus}")




#View for update  ../client/main/_update_weather.html.erb
<script>
$("#county_select").empty()
.append("<%=j render(:partial => @county_name) %>") 
</script>

<% @county_name.each do |a| %>
<option value="<%= a.id %>"><%= a.county_name %></option>
<% end %>

#view which trying to update ../client/main/_location.html.erb
<% content_for :head do %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'location', :media => "all", 'data-turbolinks-
track' => true %>
<% end %>

<%= select_tag "state", options_for_select(state_code) {},
{ id: 'state_select' } %>
<%= f.select :weathers_id, options_for_select(@county_name.collect {|a|
[a.county_name, a.id] }, 0), {}, { id: 'county_select' } %>
```

#Console output

```
Started GET "/account/main/_update_weather?state_code=CA" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-17 22:49:11 -0700
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 10 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
Processing by Client::MainController#_update_weather as HTML
Parameters: {"state_code"=>"CA"}
Rendering client/main/_update_weather.html.erb
Weather Load (3.4ms)  SELECT `weathers`.* FROM `weathers` WHERE (state_code = 'CA')
Rendered collection of client/weathers/_weather.js.erb [56 times] (0.7ms)
Rendered client/main/_update_weather.html.erb (8.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 17ms (Views: 12.0ms | ActiveRecord: 3.4ms)
```

Comment: you passing  _update_weather as HTML. Why ? It should be js. it is very simple function you dont need to follow tutorial .

Comment: @Vishal if i'm passing as dataType: 'script' i'm getting parser error

Comment: try to pass ` dataType: 'js'` else simply dont pass `dataType` just add .js in path like `'main/_update_weather.js`

Comment: I tried, it's still giving me parser error, but I see successfully generated response with list of county, but it is not replacing "#county_select"

Comment: i can't see any code for changing `$("#country_select")` . you need to add code for that